# $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{Z})$'s properties as a Lie algebra over a ring

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I was wondering what was known about $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as a Lie algebra; in particular, what is known about its representation theory? I know of some texts which treat Lie algebras generally over rings, but I haven't seen any that specifically discuss this example. It would be wonderful if there existed some analogue of a Clebsch-Gordan decomposition for tensor products of $V_n$ (by which I mean the irreps in the complex case), even if they are no longer irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Thank you very much!

Comment: In "they are no longer irreducible" what do you refer to as "they"?

Comment: @YCor Hello! I am referring to the $V_n$.

Comment: Considering complex or integer representations (eg the Vn are defined over Z)? If integer representations, what do you mean by irreducibility? Eg the multiples of 2 in Vn form a nontrivial proper submodule.

Comment: One must choose a form of the $V_n$. For instance, one may define them to be symmetric powers of the standard two dimensional representation. Then $V_n\otimes V_m$ has a "good filtration" whose layers are given by Clebsch-Gordan. See the book of Jantzen (Representations of Algebraic Groups: Second Edition)?